Find the occurence frequency of the most frequent bucket for a column - polars
Update: This issue has been fixed. The query now runs as expected.
df.group_by("a").agg(
    pl.col("c").cut([11,14]).value_counts().sort()
      .struct.field("count").first()
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘


Example:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'b':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],'c':[10,10,12,13,14,15,16,17]})
print(df)
output:
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 10  │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 10  │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 12  │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 13  │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 14  │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 15  │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 16  │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 17  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

Now, I want to find the occurrence frequency of the most prevalent item in the column c_bucket where c_bucket is   pl.col("c").cut([11,14])
I have achieved it like so:
df.select(pl.col("c").cut([11,14]).value_counts().sort().struct.field("count").first())
output:
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────┐
│ count │
│ ---   │
│ u32   │
╞═══════╡
│ 2     │
└───────┘

So far so good. Now I want to do the exact same thing within group_by('a'). I try the following code:
df.group_by("a").agg(pl.col("c").cut([11,14]).value_counts().sort().struct.field("count").first())

I get:
PanicException: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value

What am I doing wrong that I am getting this error and what is the correct way to achieve what I want to do?

You just need to create a different data frame for the inner operation and then pass that to the agg like - fltrd_df = df.select(pl.col("c").cut([11,14]).value_counts().sort().struct.field("count").first())
print(df.group_by("a").agg(fltrd_df)["count"][0])

It looks like a "bug" in Polars - it can be reported https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues - It runs if you switch the order: pl.col("c").cut([11, 14]).value_counts().sort().first().struct["count"]

Also, is that .sort() doing what you expect? The max value should be 3 - right?

I quickly typed out the example.. In the actual code I'm using  descending = True set up. The code also works if I convert the output of cut to string type

Also, Can I do it without the O(nlogn) sort operation. Since I only need to find the max it should be possible to do it in O(n)

The issue seems to be related to the cat type returned by .cut being part of the struct column. You can apply .max() to avoid the O(nlogn) sort operation after casting to pl.String.
pl.col("c").cut([11,14]).cast(pl.String).value_counts().struct.field("count").max().

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but if you do df.with_columns(pl.len().over(pl.col("c").cut([11,14]).over("a"))) - it seems like you then want the max len for each a?
